# How do I leave the Vault?

Tags: diablo-iii

When you get transported to the Vault, after the boss fight beyond the goblin portal, is there way to leave that doesn't involve using a town portal?

I was in the middle of a bounty when I got transported and there's not an easy way to get back to where I started if I have to go back to town. Is there some kind of portal or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way out but to go to town. For those who aren't entirely aware of the the way these unfold, here is a simple version:

1. A goblin's death spawns a pure gold portal
   [image: Cropped screenshot of portal]
2. Entering the portal takes you to the goblin rift<sup>(*)</sup>
   [image: Cropped screenshot in rift]
3. The rift is very short (contains no timer or progress) and is filled mostly with jars that contain millions of gold when broken.
   [image: Cropped screenshot showing gold on the ground]
4. Inside of the rift there are a series of the doors, and after moving through the rift there is the final door to the vault called "The Inner Sanctum"
   [image: Cropped screenshot showing the door]
5. Once this door is entered then you encounter the boss, "Greed"
   [image: Cropped screenshot of the boss]

So here is the thing, once the inner sanctum has been entered, and Greed defeated, there is no way out. You cannot go back, and there are no portal options to click on. The only option is to use a town portal, or to use the map to port to a waypoint or city.

However, you can still enter the goblin rift from the golden portal spawned by the goblin, this never closes. All you need to do is run back (which may take some time depending on its location).

Heck, at least you made it in :)

<sub>(*) Technically, this is the "Treasure Realm" and the boss "Greed" is in "The Inner Sanctum", but everyone tends to refer to the encounter as a whole as the goblin rift. It is not an actual rift.</sub>

Comment: Just to add that there exists Rainbow goblin that spawns a portal to Wyrmshire... don't be fooled!

Comment: Though the idea of the Wyrmshire is simultaneously awesome and terrifying, I think you meant Whimsyshire ?

Comment: i wouldn't call it a "goblin rift". It's not a rift, it's a special area, and has no relation to rifts.

Comment: @DLeh - That is essentially what everyone calls it. I know it isn't an actual rift (but it does contain a legendary gem at the end). I made an edit to show the actual names.

Comment: It's actually called Whimsydale.  But it's essentially the exact same as Whimsyshire.

Comment: Frank is correct. Here is a *[blue post](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11760996118#7)* stating that the only difference is the name - aside from the fact that it opens from a "Rainbow Goblin".